# Hiding the text of a link

Tags: css, font-awesome

I want to use a fontawesome icon for my home page link.

with this css;

```
#menu-item-47 a::before {
 content: "\f017";
 font-family: fontawesome;
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #333;
}
```

All fine and dandy, but when things get responsive I want the link text "home" to appear. How do I hide the link text without hiding the icon?

I can use `width: 15px; overflow: hidden` but that doesn't seem awfully elegant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to use `visibility: hidden;` on your element and `visibility: visible;` on the before.

```
div {
  visibility: hidden;
}

div:before {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

This solution should work fine if you don't care about your div still taking up space after it's hidden.

Comment: Perfect (and lightning swift) Thank you. (the space i can control with `width:20px` if there's no text there. )

Comment: No problem! Glad to help :)

Comment: Very nice solution! I don't think I've come across this solution before.  Only thing to bear in mind is that this doesn't collapse the space in the DOM that the hidden text took up.  I was playing with it, so this solution in combination with overflow hidden can help with that as well. https://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/jqh3a99w/. Using `em` will help make it dynamic because a logo image of this nature should generally be about `1em` in width.